# How to prove that 12:3 will always be 4

Tags: arithmetic

I got this riddle that I just couldnt solve.
It's simple, how can you prove that a:b will always be C ?
(a, b and c are natural numbers)
For example 12:3=4, 4 will be the only solution.

Comment: What do you mean by $a:b$?

Comment: Natural number divided by another natural number

Comment: This is one of those questions that sound so simple it actually reduces to working out the construction of the natural numbers and their arithmetic. Are you interested in a resource that formally describes the natural numbers and how to prove things about them?

Comment: If there's a refrence for this specific question, then yes, otherwise it wont help much.

Comment: What do you mean by "always"? Mathematical facts are not time dependent.

Comment: If you will divide a number by abother number there will only be one answer, how can you prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by writing $a/b$ as an expression, you're sort of assuming that it is "well-defined", that is, it has exactly one value. Otherwise, there might be a scenario where you could say $a/b \ne a/b$, which would be absurd. So I'll rephrase the question.

If $b \ne 0$ (can't divide by $0$), $a = bc$ and $a = bc'$, how do we know that $c = c'$?

Proof:
$$ bc = bc' \implies bc - bc' = 0 \implies b(c - c') = 0$$
In the integers, if two things multiply to $0$, at least one is $0$. Since $b \ne 0$, we know that $c - c' = 0$, and so $c = c'$.

Note that this is essentially a proof that division is well-defined.

Comment: This is it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Euclidean Division Theorem states that when you divide 2 natural numbers (except for division by 0) a quotient and remainder exist, and are unique. [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Proof)